# Bitrate-MediaInfo

Tags: bitrate, media-info

What is the BitRate_Maximum/String (for video and audio) which I've been seeing on MediaInfo (What does "String" means here?) ?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I've seen this for Mainconcept H.264 encodes - i.e. you set a max bitrate and an avg bitrate during render and the reading you are seeing seems to be the max.

Answer (score 3):

> What does "String" means here?

You are using internal names of MediaInfo, not intended in an output for human beings.
Here, "/String" means that it is not the reference version, only something "translatede from the reference field (here: "BitRate_Maximum", a value in bps e.g. 10000000, and the corresponding "/String" version provides a value + unit e.g. "10 Mbps").

> What is the BitRate_Maximum

with a file with variable bit rate, it is the maximum more or less instantaneous bit rate. It may be read from metadata (e.g. bit_rate_value from AVC/H.264) or from frame size (e.g. MP4 has the list of frame sizes in the header so we can see which frame is the biggest one).